# clearTimeout() not clearing timer

Tags: javascript, html, css, cleartimeout

```
function countDown(secs,elem)
{   
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Game ends in " + secs + " seconds!";
    if(secs<1)
    {   
        clearTimeout(timer);
        document.getElementById('gameContent').style.display='none';

    }
    secs--;
    var timer = setTimeout('countDown('+secs+',"'+elem+'")',1000);

}

 <div class="timerCount" id="status"></div>
 <script>countDown(5,"status");</script>
```

My timer starts correctly at 5 secs and decrements. My game div hides after the timer reaches 0 but the timer doesnt clear out and end instead it goes to negative. Please my bug in my code so as to stop the timer and clear it

Comment: `clearTimeout(timer);` `timer` is null everytime. You declare `timer` as the last variable in your function - how do you ever expect it to be accessed before hand?

Comment: declare `timer` outside of the `countDown` method.  It needs to persist between method calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more efficient if you just use `setInterval` and do something like this:

```js
function countDown(secs, elem) {
  var interval;
  var element = document.getElementById(elem);
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    secs--;
    update();
    if (secs < 1) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);

  function update() {
    if (secs > 0) {
      element.innerHTML = "Game ends in " + secs + " seconds!";
    } else {
      document.getElementById('gameContent').style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  update();

}

countDown(5, "status");
```

```html
<div id="gameContent">
  <h1>Game</h1>
  <div class="timerCount" id="status"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The clearing of the timeout makes no sense, since you are in the callback invoked by the timeout you want to clear, so there really is nothing to clear. Even if you would declare `timer` as a global variable, that would still not deal with that conceptual issue.

Your problem really is that you still call `setTimeout` after your seconds have run out. So, exit the function before doing so (or use `else`):

```
function countDown(secs,elem)
{   
    var element = document.getElementById(elem);
    element.innerHTML = "Game ends in " + secs + " seconds!";
    if(secs<1)
    {   
        document.getElementById('gameContent').style.display='none';
        return; // <-------- add this!
    }
    secs--;
    // avoid passing string as first argument to setTimeout:
    setTimeout(countDown.bind(null, secs, elem),1000);
}
```

NB: it is considered bad practice to pass a string as first argument to `setTimeout`: that string will need to be evaluated, just like with `eval`. Besides the reservations that programmers have with `eval`, it is also less efficient and unnecessary in this case.